# Send email through procedure

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, bulk

I need to execute the bulk update in procedure. in that time if error occurs i need to pass that on trigger after that trigger needs to send an email to my email id?

```
    If((select COUNT(*) 
from dbo.Solr_sync_status 
where solr_sync_id=1 and solr_Status=1 and solr_message like '%Error%')>0) 
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SQL SERVER ALERT', @recipients='aaah@yyyy.com'
, @subject='Sync Status'
, @Query='select * from [temp].dbo.syncstatus where solrmessage like "%Error%"' 
end
```

Comment: Which SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: May http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx helps

Comment: I refered this already.. my problem is when i am executing it's locking spid id.

Comment: Give some sample code @Ramesh. So that will be very easy to frlan to help you..

Comment: @Ramesh: Please post more details on what did you do.

Comment: If((select COUNT(*) from dbo.Solr_sync_status where solr_sync_id=1 and solr_Status=1 and solr_message like '%Error%')>0)
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='SQL SERVER ALERT',      @recipients='aaah@yyyy.com',      @subject='Sync Status', @Query='select * from [temp].dbo.syncstatus where solrmessage like "%Error%"'
end

Comment: I have a proc.. when i am running that it will update multiple rows if error occurring i need to pass that error to trigger above posted code will check the condition and send an email to my id

Comment: You are executing a code, if the code crash, you are "executing" a trigger that will send a mail? And what after, the store proc continue to execute the end of the code? Why don't you use a try catch block? Another thing i'm not sure, sending mail is asynchronous, in a trigger, i think it's not deterministic (but i think i tried and it works :) ). Why do you need to invoke a trigger? Ask to your trigger before update to check the insert and if it crashes, it sends an email but i'm not sure it won't slow your process

Comment: @MatheseF DBMail procedures like `sp_send_dbmail` send mail asynchronously.  They are OK to use in a Trigger (though I do agree that A trigger is not the way to catch an error).

Comment: Thanks Friends to share your feedbacks.